# Universal iOS application

Tags: ios

We have an iPhone app and want it to support iPad also.

But as I learned if you submit an app to Apple and indicate it is Universal, while in reality it is not (for example iPad is not supported at the time of submission, this is restricted by their policy).

So, what is the best way that we simultaneously allow further development of our application such that we also support iPad?

**ps:** we didn't want to create separate projects for iPad and iPhone since they share lot of code, but as I mentioned we encountered following obstacles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit your app as an iPhone app. When you support iPad change it to a universal app when you submit your update.

Comment: that sounds reasonable to me. so you think if I make iPad related changes to project while I have not selected the "Universal" option in XCode, it will be alright?

Comment: This is about the comment not the answer as that is correct. If you make an iPhone app that is not iPad supported and you run it on an iPad it will run in a window simpler to the simulator on the iPad with a `x2` in the bottom corner. It does it this way because it believes it is an iPhone and not an iPad as such you will not be able to do somethings, like detect the iPad screen size (will return iPhone screen size), use the iPad specific UI Components, and many more. It will always think it is an iPhone until you support iPad correctly. This adds a huge restriction.

Comment: Do not misunderstand running on iPad for iPad supported. Unless it is "Universal" you should not consider it iPad Support. Telling someone it is iPad/iPhone supported when it is not "Universal" is misleading as it is only iPhone supported until you change.